# CSS Menu and submenu overwrite style

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I make sure that the sub menu does not use any style from the main menu? What Im using seems to keep taking style from the .nav-left li.link a and .nav-left li.link a:hover.

```
#nav {position:relative; width:960px;}
#nav .nav-left, .nav-right {position:relative;}
#nav .nav-left ul, .nav-right ul {margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav .nav-left li, .nav-right li {float:left; position:relative; list-style:none;}
#nav .nav-left li.logo a {position:static;}
#nav .nav-left li.item, .nav-right li.item {position:relative;}
#nav .nav-left li.link a, .nav-right li.link a {}
#nav .nav-left li.link a:hover, .nav-right li.link a:hover {}
#nav .nav-left li:hover a {}
#nav .nav-left li.active a, .nav-right li.active a {}
#nav .nav-left li.active a:hover, .nav-right li.active a:hover {}
#nav .nav-left li.first, .nav-right li.first {}
#nav .nav-left li.last, .nav-right li.last {}
#nav .nav-left ul li:hover .submenu {left:0; top:auto;}
#nav .sub-menu {position:absolute; left:-999em; width:200px;}
#nav .sub-menu ul {}
#nav .sub-menu li {display:block; position:relative; width:200px; list-style:none;}
#nav .sub-menu li a {}
#nav .sub-menu li a:hover {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). It only selects immediate children, not all descendants.

For example:

```
 .nav-left > ul {} /* only matches if ul is direct child of .nav-left */
```

It is [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) in every modern browser and also IE >= 7.